# WshShell.AppActivate doesn't seem to work in simple vbs script

Tags: windows, vbscript

I am totally new to VBScript scripting. I'm trying to automate closing a certain open window, namely a program called HostsMan. This is on Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit, and this is what my script currently looks like:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "HostsMan"
WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
```

The second line doesn't seem to work. I know line 3 works because it activates the Windows shutdown menu. Is there something I'm missing?

Manually entering <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd> does close it, so I know this should work. I also tested this script with other open windows and they close just fine. Additionally, HostsMan is opened with administrator privileges, so I tried running the script as a task set with the highest privileges to see if that would do it, and still no go. But that does work with other open windows running with administrator privileges. It is frustrating!

Comment: What's the exact title of the window (in the caption bar) that you're trying to close? Does it just say "HostsMan"?

Comment: Yeah, it just says "HostsMan". In Task Manager its listed as "HostsMan (32 bit)", which I also tried. No dice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've tried it, too, and couldn't get it to work. There must be something about the window class, perhaps, where `AppActivate` doesn't see it as a top-level window?

In any event, `AppActivate` also lets you pass the process ID instead of the window title. When I installed HostsMan, the process name was `hm.exe`, so I'll use that in my example below.

```
Set Processes = GetObject("winmgmts:").InstancesOf("Win32_Process")

For Each Process In Processes
    If StrComp(Process.Name, "hm.exe", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

        ' Activate the window using its process ID...
        With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            .AppActivate Process.ProcessId
            .SendKeys "%{F4}"
        End With

        ' We found our process. No more iteration required...
        Exit For

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thanks! Before I try your solution, does this mean that it will kill the process? If so, it won't work for my needs. I have HostsMan set to run in the tray upon close, which I need it to do, so what I really need is just a way to auto close it.

Comment: No, it just determines the process *ID* so that it can pass it to `AppActivate`.

Comment: Understood. I tried using your code above, but all it appears to do is bring HostMan's window to the top. Am I supposed to add my existing code to it somewhere for it to then close the window? PS - thanks for your patience with me on this.

Comment: Right, I was just trying to help with your `AppActivate` issue. With the window at the top, however, you should now be able to use `SendKeys` to send your "close" command (or any other key combination). I just updated my code to add the `SendKeys` statement.

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a ton, Bond. Sure learned a lot on this one.

Comment: Somehow I also have the issue that AppActivate does not work using the ProcessName but does work with the ProcessId (e.g. with Powerpoint application=POWERPNT.EXE)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution using WMIService (no loop through all processes required):

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2")
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * from Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & ProcessName & "'") 

If colItems.Count = 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Process not found"
    Wscript.Quit
End If

For Each objProcess in colItems
    WshShell.AppActivate(objProcess.ProcessId)
    Exit For
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to put a small pause after the 'run' command but before the 'appactivate' command so the application shows up in the process list.

```
     WshShell.Run "calc"
     WScript.Sleep 100
     WshShell.AppActivate "Calculator"
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem of *AppActivate*, you have to use a loop and an *if* condition statement to check if the active windows are the target windows or not, because sometime you deselect or the system deselect the target windows before executing the sendkeys directly, so you got an error.

I create this in a tight strict way:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    for i=0 to 300 ' This loop will continue about 30 seconds if this not enough increase this number
        Rtn=WshShell.AppActivate("HostsMan") ' HostMan have to be the windows title of application or its process ID
        If Rtn = True Then
            WshShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"    ' Send key to click Alt + F4 to close
            wscript.sleep 100        ' Stop executing the next line until finishing closing the application
            Rtn=WshShell.AppActivate("HostsMan")
             If Rtn=False Then ' Using a nested If to be sure of selected windows is false because it's close
               Exit For      ' Exit for loop directly and execute what after for next
             End If
        End If
        wscript.sleep 100
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim sh : Set sh =CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
sh.Exec "calc.exe"
Wscript.Sleep 1000
sh.Exec "taskkill /f /FI ""WINDOWTITLE  eq ""calc*"""
```

**OR**

```
sh.Run "taskkill /f /im calc.exe",0,False
```

Comment: Why [taskkill](https://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*