# VBScript Send Key "

Tags: vbscript, sendkeys, steam

I have a VBScript to unsubscribe all Steam Workshop-Objects

Code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.AppActivate "Steam Community :: [GER] Aaron :: Abonnierte Objekte - Opera"
WshShell.AppActivate "Steam Community :: [GER] Aaron :: Abonnierte Objekte - Opera"
WshShell.AppActivate "Steam Community :: [GER] Aaron :: Abonnierte Objekte - Opera"
WshShell.SendKeys "^{2}"
WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.SendKeys "jQuery ("[id^='UnsubscribeItemBtn']").children().trigger('click'); setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},500);"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.SendKeys "jQuery ("[id^='UnsubscribeItemBtn']").children().trigger('click'); setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},500);"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 5000
WshShell.SendKeys "jQuery ("[id^='UnsubscribeItemBtn']").children().trigger('click'); setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},500);"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

And in Line 7 (Symbol 29) it has to send a " but the Script thinks it has to end the SendKey-Command there...

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding quotes to a string in VBScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942554/adding-quotes-to-a-string-in-vbscript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is two fold;

1. The strings are not correctly escaped as [@Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/736893/scott) has [pointed out *(Revision 1)*](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41623814/1), but [their latest edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/41623814/2) isn't the way to fix that both `""` and `Chr(34)` are equivalent and personally I'd stick with escaping by doubling the quotes.
2. > Invalid procedure or argument at Line 7 Symbol 1 (Code: 800a0005)

   is likely caused by `SendKeys()` when `AppActivate()` isn't set to the correct window.

   Notice what happens in VBSEdit while running the script, the `SendKeys()` injects into the script causing the runtime error.

   [image: Screenshot]

   The way to check this is to return a Boolean from `AppActivate()` before continuing the script to make sure it is successful.

   ```vb
   Option Explicit
   Dim WshShell: Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
   Dim IsWindowActive: IsWindowActive = WshShell.AppActivate("Steam Community :: [GER] Aaron :: Abonnierte Objekte - Opera")
   If IsWindowActive Then
       WshShell.SendKeys "^{2}"
       WScript.Sleep 5000
       WshShell.SendKeys "jQuery (""[id^='UnsubscribeItemBtn']"").children().trigger('click'); setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},500);"
       WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
       WScript.Sleep 5000
       WshShell.SendKeys "jQuery (""[id^='UnsubscribeItemBtn']"").children().trigger('click'); setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},500);"
       WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
       WScript.Sleep 5000
       WshShell.SendKeys "jQuery (""[id^='UnsubscribeItemBtn']"").children().trigger('click'); setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},500);"
       WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
   Else
       WScript.Echo "Activating Window Failed"
   End If
   ```

   Output *(because I don't have that particular Window)*:

   ```
   Activating Window Failed
   ```

   #### Why does `AppActivate()` return `False`?

   As to working out why `AppActivate()` returns `False` I'd recommend reviewing

   [A: WshShell.AppActivate doesn't seem to work in simple vbs script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23184667/692942).

Comment: Nope still doesnt work...i guess because im using Windows 10 ? I tested  a little bit and i never got app.activate to work...

Comment: @AaronB wait the code errors *(tested)* or you get "Activating Window Failed" returned?

Comment: @AaronB I've explained why you were getting the error you posted on Scott's answer *(since removed)*, which I'm pretty sure I've done. Your problem now is getting `AppActivate()` to return `True` which is likely due to the WindowClass of the Window see [A: WshShell.AppActivate doesn't seem to work in simple vbs script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23184667/692942).

Comment: I got Activating Window Failed. I looked the Question you linked and if i understood i just need to put in the appactivate "opera.exe" ? Im not a Coding pro...

Comment: @AaronB which is what I suspected. You need to study that linked answer, but passing the executable name won't work, it's either the Window Title but if that fails the Process Id *(which is a numerical value assigned for the life of the process)* which you can get by following Bonds approach using WMI. Either way I'm pretty sure your initial query has been answered, if you find this or other answers useful consider leaving an up-vote and if question answered your initial question consider accepting it. Hope this has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the hard way that sendkey does its 'translations' on some keys. See the table at `https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx`

Unfortunately, I did not find a way to put `SendKey` in 'raw' mode to not interpret. So I have to process the string to pre-undo the translation. Since I use `PowerShell`, I use the next 2 lines:

```
${SendKeyStr2Type} = "${Str2Type}" -replace "([\\{\\}\\[\\]\\(\\)~+^%])",'{$1}'
$wshell.SendKeys("${SendKeyStr2Type}")
```

Details: After -replace there are 2 strings, regex style. The first lists the characters to escape `{}[]()~+^%`. They are escaped for regex using `\\`. That is in `[]-s` to get a selection of one of them. That is in `()-s` to be used in the next (replace) string. The second string is `$1`, the regex way to type the found string (single character here) and type it between `{}-s`.

Keep in mind, `sendkey` sends `key-strokes`. They took the liberty to use some characters at `<shift><othercaracter>` to be able to type keys that do not have their character.