# Single shift key in VBS

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to write a vbs script that has to send the shift key once. I dont need any other key pressed after it but I can't get it to work (I want to use only vbs not any other progarm nor another language). I've tried things like:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.SendKeys "+{}"
```

or

```
WshShell.SendKeys "+"
```

or

```
WshShell.SendKeys {+}
```

or

```
WshShell.SendKeys +
```

and many more but nothing seems to work.
Thank you in advance!
-Sandro Cutri

Comment: Where are you trying to send the keystrokes to? If it's to a specific application you might want to checkout - [WshShell.AppActivate doesn't seem to work in simple vbs script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23184667)

Comment: No, I just want it to simulate a key"press". It doesen't have to send it to a specific window.

Comment: So what's the keystroke for if not to cause an interaction with an application?

Comment: If you press shift 5 times it opens the sticky key option. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I know that I can just search for sticky keys via windows search and activate it like that, but that's not what I want.

Comment: Isn't that the default behaviour in Windows already?

Comment: It is. But my question was how I can send the shift key once via a vbs script. (Important: Just the shift key - nothing else)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send a shift key (without anything else) with the Duck toolkit. It's a free webside. It "translates" your code from vbs to the ducky language (it turns it into a inject.bin file). I assume that that's what you want to do. From there you can write

```
SHIFT
```

That's all you need to write. It's important to write in CAPITAL letters.

Comment: You're Welcome! Are you trying to use a rubber ducky?

Comment: Yes. I bought it about a week ago and I am trying to learn it :D